# Mongoose Map of Map, is not working for me

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Mongoose model, that should store Objects of Objects.

This is an example of element I want to store:

```js
    var company = new Company({
      documents : {
                    "outerKey1": {"innerKey1": {name:"xxx"}, "innerKey2": {name:"yyy"}},
                    "outerKey2": {"innerKey1": {name:"xxx"}}
                  }
    })
```

So I defined the model as follow:

```js
    var InnerMapSchema = new Schema({
     type : Map,
     of : {
             name:   {type:String}
          }
    });


    var OuterMapSchema = new Schema({
       type : Map,
       of : InnerMapSchema,
       default:{}
      });

    var CompanySchema = new Schema({
         documents: {type: OuterMapSchema}
    });
```

Anyway it's not woking, I can't save neither a document.

```js
function save_MapElement(company_id, inner_key, outer_key, name)
{
  var company = Company.findById(company_id); // it's async in reality
  if(!company.documents) { company.documents = {}; }
  if(!company.documents.get(outer_key) { company.documents.set(outer_key, {}); }

   company.documents.get(outer_key).set(inner_key, {"name":name});
   company.save();
}
```

I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined` when trying to use `.set()`.
Why? How does it work?

```
$ npm mongoose --version
$ 6.4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize company.documents as a mongoose Map object if it doesn't already exist.  In my code, I solved this by adding a method to my schema to accomplish this that I call whenever I need to create the map on a document that doesn't already have it:

```
presentationProgress: {
    type: Map,
    of: {
        highestDecimalCompletion: Number,
        longestTimeDwelled: Number
    }
}
...
userSchema.methods.initializePresentationProgressMap = function() {
    this.presentationProgress = new Map();
}
```

In your case, I think you just need to update `company.documents = {}` to `company.documents = new Map()` and `.set(outer_key, {})` to `.set(outer_key, new Map()`.  I haven't tried this with nested maps as your code uses, but I think it should probably work.  I know it doesn't work if you don't call the `Map()` constructor.

Comment: thank you for you answer. I solved using `Schema.Types.Mixed`, and than using `obj.markModified('field_name')`. Anyway I'll try your solution next time.